# Cloudkit JS sample code?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, css, cloudkit-web-services

I have an iOS app using Cloudkit and now I'm developing a web application (with HTML5, CSS and Javascript) to register users.
I already read the documentation and follow some tutorials, but nothings seems to work. Sometimes there is no error, so i really don't know what i'm doing wrong.
Can somebody post a sample code of how I can use Cloudkit JS to save and fetch datas?
It's important to say that i'm developping it in Visual Studio.
Please, I'm really desperate!

Answer (score 1):

Tow samples I found useful:
1. CloudKit-catalog from Apple:
https://cdn.apple-cloudkit.com/cloudkit-catalog
2. iOS9 Day-by-Day :: Day 13 :: CloudKit Web Services
https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios9-day-by-day-day13-cloudkit-web-services
Both are easy to set up and run.
Have fun!